# Calculate height of the element w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to assign a height to an element based on the height of the screen. I have content going past the screen fold, so I can not use

```
$(window).height();
```

Is there a way to calculate the height of the visible part of the open window?

Comment: What do you mean "height of the visible part"? Which is the *invisible* part?

Comment: $(window).height(); will show the window size but $(document).height(); will show the whole document height including scrolling part. It should do the job.

Comment: @Jon Anything below screen fold is invisible ;)

Comment: @Jey, you're right. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: The *invisible part* is where we usually keep our cup of coffee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it is like so:

```
var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
```

This will fallback based on browser support

Answer (score 2):

To get the visible height of the element you would subtract the `offetTop` of the element from the `height` of the window.

```
var elTop = $("#element").offset().top;
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var elVisibleHeight = winHeight - elTop;
```

If `elVisibleHeight < 0` then the element is below the screen fold and not visible. If you needed to keep track of the element's position, you'd need to update this on window `scroll`.

**UPDATE**

I've created a fiddle with a working example of the theory. Obviously you can shorten this, I've left it pretty verbose so it's more clear as to what is happening.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVUdB/)

Answer (score 2):

This will show you the difference of document or window height.

http://jsfiddle.net/9YFwx/